# How elastic beanstalk's log rotate in s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I need some help to understand  how the log rotation works for elastic beanstalk. We use Amazon AMI and Tomcat 7 over a year in Amazon, now we need to go back and check the logs since last October. I found some logs under elasticbeanstalk-us-west1-1/enviorments/logs/publish/e-v2xxxxxx. Is it true that under this path contains all the logs for this environment? Thanks!